# CSS Style only text within a paragraph tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page of text and it is formatted similar to this

```
<div class="container">
    <p style="text-align: center;">
        <span style="text-decoration: underline;">
            <strong>
                <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0652/9219/files/Horizontal.jpg?13817493546805475501" alt="">
            </strong>
        </span>
    </p>
    <p style="text-align: center;">
        <span style="text-decoration: underline;">
            <strong>The Hosting</strong>
        </span>
    </p>
    <p>
        The in-laws are arriving, friends are in town, and everyone is heading to your abode for a night filled with holiday cheer. As stress levels tend to rise during these events, expenses do as well. Here are a few tips to nail your hostess game, without breaking the bank and <em>still</em> shopping consciously. 
    </p>
</div>
```

I am looking to keep the images which fit the entire content width of the class container the same but only change the text within the paragraph tags to either be a smaller width (so it looks indented on both sides) or have margins but not affect the images at all.  I cannot change how the code is outputted so the images will always be wrapped in paragraph tags.

This code is a small sample on the page of content and there are several images and text throughout.

So basically I am looking for a way in css to style only the actual text within the paragraph tags and leave the images unchanged.  Any help would be great.

Here is a fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/jpautt8v/

Comment: Is there some existing CSS that goes with this?  It would be helpful to know what's already in place.

Comment: I will add to the original.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. You want the text to have a larger side margin than the images?

Comment: I would like the text with the paragraph tags to be around 80% width and keep the images within the paragraph tags to be 100% that they are.. but both are within the paragraph tags...

Comment: hi @isherwood please you could help me to create a tag `ingram-micro`, i'm not able yet.

Comment: Also, are you saying you cannot modify the existing HTML? If you CAN modify it, just use CSS classes - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVRRPV

Comment: post fiddle link with your code.

Comment: I cannot update the existing HTML easily because it is dynamically created through an editor (CMS).

Comment: Do you have more examples showing how content with multiple images are marked up?

Comment: Added a fiddle example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your html is static or if you know which child you want to modify then you could simply use the nth child css selector to apply css like below 3rd in your sample code case. You could play around margins and see what works best for your solution.

```
p:nth-child(3) 
{
   margin: 0 50px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing any of the existing markup, you can accomplish what you want using negative margin.

Something like this will work:

```
img {
  width: 120%; max-width: 120%;
  margin: 0 -10%;
}

.content > div, .content > p {
  margin: 0 10%;
}
```

You can see it working in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/jpautt8v/1/